# Remove all occurrences of element in list using Tail Recursion and Match expression

Tags: scala, tail-recursion

The task is to remove all occurrences of element in a list using Tail Recursion and Match expression.

```
remove(List(2, 1, 4, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2), 1), should return : List(2, 4, 3, 3, 2)
```

This is a pseudocode, which works only for the first occurance. Can someone guide me how to do it so it would remove all occurances?
pseudocode

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec
object Test extends App{
  def remove[A](l: List[A], el: A): List[A] = {
    @tailrec
    def helper(l: List[A], acc: List[A] = List[A]()): List[A] = {
      l match {
        case head :: tail if (head != el) => helper(tail, head::acc)
        case head :: tail if (head == el) => (acc.reverse ::: tail)
        case _ => acc
      }
    }
    helper(l)
  }
  print(remove(List(2, 1, 4, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2), 1))
}
```

Comment: Your case where `head == el` is not recursive. That's why only the first matching element gets discarded.

Comment: You know you can just do: `def remove[A](l: List[A], el: A): List[A] = l.filter(_ != el)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second pattern is not recursive, indeed its ending the recursion with the entire tail at the first match.

Further hint: you are building the accumulator in the reverse order, you can avoid the need to eventually reverse it with :+ to append in queue

```
def remove[A](l: List[A], el: A): List[A] = {
  @tailrec
  def helper(l: List[A], acc: List[A] = List[A]()): List[A] = {
    l match {
      case head +: tail => helper(tail, if(head != el) acc:+head else acc)
      case _ => acc
    }
  }

  helper(l)
}
print(remove(List(2, 1, 4, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2), 1))
```

as per jwvh comments this should be faster

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

def remove[A](l: List[A], el: A): List[A] = {
  @tailrec
  def helper(l: List[A], acc: List[A] = List[A]()): List[A] = {
    l match {
      case head +: tail => helper(tail, if(head != el) head+:acc else acc)
      case _ => acc.reverse
    }
  }

  helper(l)
}
print(remove(List(2, 1, 4, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2), 1))
```

Comment: Appending to a `List` is a linear operation. It's usually faster to prepend all the elements and then `.reverse` when it's complete.

Answer (score 0):

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec
object Zad3lab04 extends App{
  def remove[A](l: List[A], el: A): List[A] = {
    @tailrec
    def helper(l: List[A], acc: List[A] = List[A]()): List[A] = {
      l match {
        case head :: tail if (head != el) => helper(tail, head::acc)
        case head :: tail if (head == el) => helper(tail, acc)
        case _ => acc
      }
    }
    helper(l)
  }
  print(remove(List(2, 1, 4, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2), 1))
}
```

this works, prints list in diffrent order, if someone know why you could tell me. But it works so its fine.

Comment: see my answer: you are building the accumulator in reverse order. head::acc instead of acc:+head